# Should I replace fragment or modify current one?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

- Fragments can be added/replaced/removed dynamically in the code. I have been using this method for my projects.
- However I wonder what would be the difference (mainly in performance) if instead of creating a new fragment and adding it or replacing the current one, we just grab a handle to the current one and modify it.
- For example, consider this simple scenario where the only purpose of a fragment is to display an image, and we want to modify that image:

Option 1) Create a new instance of my Fragment class and replace the fragment which is currently displayed:

```
MyFragmentClass fr = new MyFragmentClass();
fr.setImage(1);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.frame_layout_id, f)
...
```

Option 2) Just grab a reference to the currently displayed fragment and modify it:

```
MyFragmentClass fr = (MyFragmentClass)
                fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout_id);
fr.setImage(1);
```

Is the whole process of creating a new fragment instance and adding it more efficient than calling findFragmentById?

Answer (score 0):

Go through following information may be you get clarification

**1- fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(str);**
Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

**2- fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)**
It replace an existing fragment that was added to a container.

This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

**3- fragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)**
Add a fragment to the activity state. This fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) into a container view of the activity.

What does it mean to replace an already existing fragment, and adding a fragment to the activity state and adding an activity to the back stack ?

There is a stack in which all the activities in the running state are kept. Fragments belong to the activity. So you can add them to embed them in a activity.

When you navigate to the current layout, you have the id of that container to replace it with the fragment you want.

You can also go back to the previous fragment in the backStack with the popBackStack() method. For that you need to add that fragment in the stack using addToBackStack() and then commit() to reflect. This is in reverse order with the current on top.

```
findFragmentByTag does this search for tag added by the add/replace method or the addToBackStack method ?
```

If depends upon how you added the tag. It then just finds a fragment by its tag that you defined before either when inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction.

Comment: Yeah, i know how the fragment transaction system works. My question was not really that. 
I want to know why or when to use this procedure instead of just finding the current fragment (not replacing it) and modify its views directly. 

So basically the same than when you want to modify an Activity. You don´t replace that activity by a new one, instead you get a reference to its views and modify them.